# How can I start the Google App Engine Java development server from JUnit?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, testing

I want to write automated tests that run against the local development web server. It's easy enough to write tests against the underlying services (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting), but I'd like to test my full stack. I could start and kill the server using Runtime.exec(), but I'm hoping someone has developed a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [the Javadocs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/). Use [DevAppServerTestRunner](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/DevAppServerTestRunner.html):

```
@RunWith(DevAppServerTestRunner.class)
@DevAppServerTest(EndToEndTest.TestConfig.class)
public class EndToEndTest {

  private final LocalServiceTestHelper testHelper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
    new LocalURLFetchServiceTestConfig(), new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

  public static class TestConfig extends BaseDevAppServerTestConfig {

    public File getSdkRoot() {
      return new File(...);
    }

    public File getAppDir() {
      return new File(...);
    }

    public List<URL> getClasspath() {
      return Arrays.asList(...);
    }
  }

  @Before
  public void setUpHelper() {
    testHelper.setUp();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDownHelper() {
    testHelper.tearDown();
  }

  @Test
  public void testEndToEnd() throws Exception {
    URLFetchService fetchService = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
    HTTPResponse resp = fetchService.fetch(new URL("http://localhost:8080/insertFoo?id=33"));
    Assert.assertEquals(200, resp.getResponseCode());
    DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().get(KeyFactory.createKey("foo", 33));
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share what values you returned for the remaining `DevAppServerTestConfig` methods you implemented?